# After giving input in command prompt after entering ENTER KEY to get output it takes me back to the blue screen and not showing output in turbo c7

Tags: c

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main ()
{
    char Ch 
    Ch = getchar();

    printf("Input Char is %c", Ch);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please copy/paste the *exact* code. By "blue screen" do you mean the blue Turbo C text editing screen, or the Windows blue "screen of death"?

Comment: Note that `getchar()` leaves a newline in the input buffer. I can't replicate this with the equivalent MSVC code (after correcting the typo), but maybe Turbo C does not distinguish the buffer from console input (`getch`) and `stdin` input (`getchar`).

Comment: Yes it is a blue screen of turbo editor

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a ; at the end of (char Ch) line .
Just try

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> //for system pause 
#include<conio.h>
void main ()
{
    char Ch ;
    Ch = getchar();

    printf("Input Char is %c", Ch);
    getch();
    system("pause");// this will keep the output there after the program execution is done , so you can observe it.

}
```

Comment: So what was the `getch();` for? I don't think this fully answers the question.

Comment: @WeatherVane
I think the buffer of input is not clear on executing this line of code and has whatever enter or space escape sequences  so the compiler exist quickly ?